# Extending a section to a basis of sections in a trivial bundle.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, obstruction-theory

Suppose we have a manifold $M$ of dimension $m$ and let $E$ be the rank $n$ trivial vector bundle on $M$. Let $\Gamma$ be a section of the trivial bundle $E$. My question is, are there some conditions on the section $\Gamma$ which ensure that it extends to a basis of sections of the vector bundle $E$.

I know that in general this is not possible (for example in case of the trivial bundle on sphere) but I am unable to see what exactly is the obstruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trivial bundle defines a line subbundle $L \subset E$; you're asking precisely that $E/L$ also be trivial. But as you point out in the question, the tangent bundle $TS^2$ plus a trivial line bundle is the trivial 3-plane bundle, so there is a line subbundle of the trivial 3-plane bundle that gives $TS^2$ as its quotient (and hence every other section of the trivial rank 3 bundle must, at some point, be a scalar multiple of our "special" one.)

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer If I am not mistaken you seem to be answering the question when the quotient is $TS^2$ but not when is it trivial.

Comment: @happymath I'm giving an example where the quotient is not trivial. Being able to extend a section to a basis of sections is the same thing as the quotient being trivial.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear but I already know of this example that is why I wanted some conditions on section which ensure the quotient is trivial

Comment: There is nothing simpler than what you and I have said.

Comment: I am looking for a condition for a vector bundle over any manifold not just the sphere

Comment: The condition I gave - that $E/L$ is a trivial bundle - has nothing to do with the base manifold being a sphere. It is always equivalent to your question. The *example* given, where $E/L$ needn't be trivial, was on a sphere.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood previously thanks for the answer now I get it